# How to add number or id each element in vue js?

Tags: vue.js

in my case i create dynamic form (like todo app) in another components. i want accesibility for other actions. therefore i must set id or number each created element(div). when i add increment method console shows duplicate key error.

how can i add number or id each element?

For examples: this is 1. created element,
this is 2. created element,
this is 3. created element,

some codes:

```js
 methods: {
        ...mapActions(["setAdList"]),
        ilanVer() {
            this.alert = true;
            let adListObj = {
                adName: this.adName,
                text: this.text,
                province: this.province,
                education: this.education,
                solder: this.solder,
                id: this.id
            }
            this.setAdList(adListObj);

            this.id += 1;
            console.log(this.id)
        },
    }
```

```html
<template>
<!-- eslint-disable max-len -->
<div class="ad-box">
    <h1 class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mt-2">İlanlarım</h1>
    <hr />
    <div class="ilan-list">
        <b-card :title=item.adName v-for="(item) in adList" :key="item.id" class="border border-info rounded w-50">
            <b-badge class="ml-3">{{item.id}}</b-badge>
            <p class="card-text">Aday Özellikleri: <span class="text-center">{{item.text}}</span> </p>
            <p class="card-text">Şehir: {{item.province}}</p>
            <p class="card-text">Eğitim: {{item.education}}</p>
            <p class="card-text">Askerlik: {{item.solder}}</p>
            <router-link to="/ilandetayi/:id">
                <b-button class="btn-outline-success mr-2">İlanlarıma Git</b-button>
            </router-link>
        </b-card>
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *index* when using `v-for` directive

In your case
`v-for="(item, index) in adList"` and then inside the block `index` will have values `0, 1, 2, ....`

Comment: just put it like `{{index}}` and it will show the value

Comment: this is cool. also this index begins zero. but i want begin one. not 0,1,2. like 1,2,3.

Comment: `{{index+1}}` for example

Comment: lastly, can i route with this index key to another page?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Index` item of `v-for` to define the unique id
`v-for="(item, index) in adList" :key="index"`

```
 <template> <!-- eslint-disable max-len --> <div class="ad-box">
        <h1 class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mt-2">İlanlarım</h1>
        <hr />
        <div class="ilan-list">
            <b-card :title=item.adName v-for="(item, index) in adList" :key="index" class="border border-info rounded w-50">
                <b-badge class="ml-3">{{item.id}}</b-badge>
                <p class="card-text">Aday Özellikleri: <span class="text-center">{{item.text}}</span> </p>
                <p class="card-text">Şehir: {{item.province}}</p>
                <p class="card-text">Eğitim: {{item.education}}</p>
                <p class="card-text">Askerlik: {{item.solder}}</p>
                <router-link to="/ilandetayi/:id">
                    <b-button class="btn-outline-success mr-2">İlanlarıma Git</b-button>
                </router-link>
            </b-card>
            <hr />
        </div> </div> </template

    > Blockquote
```